# fglrx fails to load causing black screen on boot

Tags: 11.04, drivers, fglrx

I've updated my system, the system boots but I never get to the graphic interface. It seems to hang.

I get a black screen, at the end of the screen, I got my cursor `_` blinking and I don't know what to do.

I believe the system is OK somehow, because I notice the screen saver activation after a while but nothing more. If I press any key, the screen savers vanishes but I just don't know how to leave from this state.

I've tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, entering `exit` but I just get the letters there, nothing happens.

At the end, my `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` has:

> DRI Initialization failed kernel
>   module (fglrx.ko) may be missing or
>   incompatible 2D and 3D acceleration
>   disabked
>
> glesx __g1ESXExtensionInit: No GL ES2.0 Capable screen found!
>
> Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
>   Server Aborting Please consult the X.org Foundadion Support (EE)
>   fglrx(0): fireg1_SetSuspendeResumeState FAILED -9
>
> ddxSigGiveUp: closing log

**UPDATE:**

I've done:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx
```

after which I've rebooted. Now I got nothing on my screen. Not even the command line.

What can I do? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: The `udev` message is almost certainly a dead end. `udev` spews out all sorts of stuff on perfectly working machines. Same with `ureadahead`. The content of `~/.xsession-errors` and `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` would be helpful.

Comment: @Oli - I've just searched and if I do alt+f2 I get the possibility to login. I have done that. But I don't know what to do more then this. :((

Comment: How can I see those lines. I tried vim filename . but I haven't installed and when I do apt-get I got some mirror errors. I've tried gnome-open filename but I get some errors as well... how can I see those files?

Comment: `nano` should be installed by default and is a fairly good editor. Failing that `less <filename>` should show you the file.

Comment: Oli I'm seeing the first file. It's to big. I have no clue how to paste it here. Perhaps the end of te file corresponds to something ?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install pastebinit` and then `pastebinit <filename>` will upload a file to Ubuntu's PasteBin service and give you back a small URL that you could post here.

Comment: I'm not sure if the mirror errors are due the fact that I don't have internet. I will give it a try. (thanks a lot for being there, I'm so stuck here. :( )

Comment: Cannot resolve mirrors.nfsi.pt - great :s

Comment: Is there any way to revert to the previous versions somehow ?

Comment: Hmm yes that might be the case. We could battle with this longer but you might do best just to see what `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` says. The final few lines *should* give you an idea of why it has crashed.

Comment: Oli: i've updated my question with the final part.

Comment: Got it... uff...

First:

1)
    sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx

2)
then we get a black screen. Restart your machine and after the bios image, press `shift + down arrow key` to enter on GRUD mode (at least I recall this name).

3)
Then choose enter on `low graphics mode` (or similar).

4)
Then you will see your desktop. Once there, do: `apt-get-update` and then, `apt-get upgrade`.

5)
    Restart your system


Great help:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1602441&page=2


Hope this helps someone one day.

Comment: @user15301 You should write that as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't have purged `flgrx`, really.

I experienced exactly same problem after updating to 11.04 (booted fine with old kernel 2.6.35, but trying to boot with default kernel of 11.04 I had blank screen and blinking cursor)
All I had to do is add `radeon.modeset=0` to grub options (along with `quiet splash`)
once you can add this option pressing <kbd>E</kbd> in grub menu for permanently editing and updating grub.

If anything, you can edit grub options doing

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

The line will look like something `... ="radeon.modeset=0 quiet splash"`.

Save the grub file then update the grub config using `sudo update-grub`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/761830

It hasn't been fixed yet, but don't despair. When you get to that black screen with the blinking cursor, you are stuck at *tty7*, which doesn't exist. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to take you to *tty1* (terminal one) where you can log in as normal. This was partially fixed from an earlier bug report so that ordinary desktop and server installations don't get this, but command line installations still do. From the topic of this thread, it apparently can happen on certain upgrades too.

I haven't found a workaround for it that I like, (editing the grub2 config files), so I just do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and will keep doing so until the patch for grub2 comes through. (I have a command line virtual machine and haven't upgraded my host yet. Just as well)

Your upgrade probably went fine, your files are probably fine, we just have this annoying bug in grub2 that doesn't let us boot to the proper interface. Yet. I'm going to wait it out rather than tinker, because everything works just great when I get past it!

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded two machines, and they are both seriously mucho deado. These two are ThinkPads, one is older under the IBM logo, while the second one is Lenovo branded. I was hoping to find some hint to proceed, but I'm obviously a fool for hoping that Ubuntu was not going to get worse this time around. I actually succeeded on an even older machine, but apparently because it rejected Unity completely.

Well, at least I'm not a perfect fool. I had already stopped relying on Ubuntu, and the two new deaders are actually only VMware Player emulators, though on two different machines.

In conclusion, I've been using Ubuntu for about 5 years now, and it peaked several years ago. To me it seems obvious that their financial model is fatally flawed, so just for grins, I thought of a better one. Here's the link in case you might find it amusing.

http://eco-epistemology.blogspot.com/2009/11/economics-of-small-donors-reverse.html