# Recover Ubuntu - after failing Update to version 11.04

Tags: updates

[fglrx fails](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37755/fglrx-fails-to-load-causing-black-screen-on-boot) to load causing black screen on boot.

I need to recover my Ubuntu (perhaps to the previous 10.10 version).

Is there a way for doing so ?

I mean, perhaps after Ubuntu tried to update, it has place some restore point that we may now use to recover ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you go to a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>)?

Then you can uninstall fglrx:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx
```

Or:

```
cd /usr/share/ati
sudo sh ./fglrx-uninstall.sh
sudo reboot now
```

References: [1](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1602441&page=2), [2](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1209837).

Comment: i've linked up his original question if you want to help there.

Comment: when I do sudo sh ./fglrx-uninstall.sh I get: "sh: Can't open ./fglrx-uninstall.sh" - when I do ls inside ati folder, I only see something called amdcccle

Comment: Obrigado Jorge Castro. Thank you Desgua. I've google it a little and I've found: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1602441&page=2 . I've removed the fglrx thing, and I'm now wondering what will happen next. :)

Comment: Please update the question (with this comment link) so that I can mark as an answer. :)