# Ubuntu doesn't start anymore after upgrading 11.04

Tags: 11.04, startup

I updated Ubuntu 10.10 to 11.04 but ubuntu doesn't start I tried to follow these :
[instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37755/fglrx-fails-to-load-causing-black-screen-on-boot/38002#38002)

but it didn't work because I couldn't enter the thing he called "GRUD mode" 
so i reinstalled --purge fglrx
and now if I start my computer there is a lot of text like:
Setting sensors limits [OK]
...
and there is on line:
Stopping automatic crash report generation [fail]

My computer is a Sony Vaio VGN-FW11J

can anyone help me?
thanks a lot

Here's a picture of my laptotp:
[image]

After a long search and a modification in the Grub data, I can access it, but does this help me ?

Comment: After all the text, what does your system do? IF you are just seeing text and then shut the computer down yourself, it's not a real problem.

Please add the detail :)

Comment: Could you either type in text, or even take a picture of the screen and upload it?

Comment: unfortunally not, there is a lot of things the system seems to check an as described one seems to fail :(

Comment: via strg alt f1 i can open a console, which works normally & in the window i described in the text above i can enter text but nothing happens

Comment: @dpb @Roland now i took a picture with my cell but I'm not quite sure how to upload it here so there it is via dropbox: [pic](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13100373/P1842_29-04-11.JPG)

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it disabling ati graphic driver from System Configuration > Additionals drivers

For the system to boot you have to change the kernel to the previous linux kernel, non-generic-pae

Answer (score 0):

Hi @ all
I just managed after a little discussion with some friends to find a solution:

1) You gotta get in the GRUB 
2) Start Ubuntu in a graphically reduced mode
3) go to System > (In German: "Zusätzliche Treiber") Additionak Drivers (?!) and install the one for your graphiccard. 
That's it.

How to get in the GRUB:
I managed this by modifying the "GRUB data" by console with nano (sudo required)
(Because I'm not quiet sure how to exactly rewrite the file I want you to look for it yourself, sorry had a little help and cannot remind exactly)
If you are in te GRUB in german there's some kind of "Recovery-Option" (Wiederherstellungsmodus) choose this one and follow till you can choose a graphically reduced start for ubuntu.

Hope this will help someone else some time, so this problem is solved and I'm looking forward working with 11.04 :)

Comment: @Rémo not quiet sure how to install the drivers via terminal because there not linked in the softwarecenter